# QGIS - rendering vector tiles

Tags: mapbox, openlayers, qgis, vector-tiles

I loaded `.shp` file inside `QGIS`, and exported it from there using `Export to PostgreSQL` command in `Processing Toolbox` pane.
Then I started `pg_tileserv.exe` to serve vector tiles, and as you can see in this screenshot - it is visible in the browser (blue contour lines).

[image]

The problem I'm having is to display these vector tiles inside QGIS if added as `XYZ Tiles` (or if I try to display in browser with my code and OpenLayers js lib.). As you can see in this screenshot, I added `XYZ Tiles`, but it just stays blank - I cannot see the map in the right pane (in screenshot, checkbox is not checked, but nothing happens even if checked. I also tried changing styles etc...):

[image]

And if I load data directly from PostgreSQL, it loads and shows OK:

[image]

Anybody knows what could be a problem here?

**UPDATE**

As @JGH said, I should use `Vector Tiles` from list. Now just to see why OpenLayers config is not rendering it:

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import MVT from 'ol/format/MVT';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import VectorTileLayer from 'ol/layer/VectorTile';
import VectorTileSource from 'ol/source/VectorTile';
import View from 'ol/View';
import {Fill, Icon, Stroke, Style, Text} from 'ol/style';

const key =
    '';

const map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new VectorTileLayer({
      declutter: true,
      source: new VectorTileSource({
        attributions:
            '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/">Mapbox</a> ' +
            '© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">' +
            'OpenStreetMap contributors</a>',
        format: new MVT(),
        url:
            'http://localhost:7800/public.simplified_land_polygons/' +
            '{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf' +
            key,
      }),
      style: createMapboxStreetsV6Style(Style, Fill, Stroke, Icon, Text),
    }),
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 1,
  }),
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

Yes, it was due to styles. After changing, it is visible now!

```
style: new Style({
  fill: new Fill({
    color: 'red'
  }),
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: 'white',
    width: 1.25
  }),
  image: new Circle({
    radius: 5,
    fill: new Fill({
      color: 'red'
    }),
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'white',
      width: 1.25
    })
  })
```

Comment: try using the `vector tiles` instead of `xyz tiles`

Comment: Thanks. That was it! :) Now, just to see why OpenLayers are also not rendering when using `VectorTileSource`. The map display is blank. Maybe I need some special styles there also? I'll update question with OpenLayers config.

Comment: @JGH Thanks, I fixed also the styles in openlayers...